# How to bring the message box other than error message box

Tags: disassembly, ollydbg

The program asks serial number. I've searched the API call which triggers the wrong password message box and force it into accepting an incorrect serial number in x64dbg’s string references. I found nothing usefull. So I tried to use Call Stack window in order to catch the responsible API function for input strings. I placed a breakpoint on the suspected address. I scrolled up to change the JE instructor to JNZ. When I click the OK button after I enter a serial number, the button doesn't work:

`0654C66D    E8 26353D01     CALL 0791FB98
0654C672    85C0            TEST EAX,EAX
0654C674    0F84 37010000   JE 0654C7B1
0654C67A    BE 05000000     MOV ESI,0x5
0654C67F    E9 41010000     JMP 0654C7C5
0654C684    FF75 14         PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x14]
0654C687    FF75 10         PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x10]
0654C68A    FF75 0C         PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0xC]
0654C68D    FF75 08         PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x8]
0654C690    8B55 DC         MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-0x24]
0654C693    8BCB            MOV ECX,EBX
0654C695    E8 B6FED7FD     CALL 042CC550`  ' I've placed the breakpoint here.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you changed some code inside MessageBox function? Please give more contextual information about the problem.

Comment: I want to make the application bring me the MessageBox function like “registration accepted.” Is it possible that I put the breakpoint on the wrong address?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific and give more details about the context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to check if which API function is responsible for input strings. I tried to find an API call by using the "Names" window. Also I have tried searching for all intermodular calls. The SendMessage and GetWindowTextA APIs are found in neither.   Likewise I can’t find the error message in Referenced String window when I enter the wrong serial number. Could the program is either packed or strings are encrypted. Should I also try the method of Ctrl+G to find the SendMessage and GetWindowTextA?

Comment: Man you should put some time organizing your thoughts and your problem in a legible easy to understand text. Also I would suggest you stop using Olly and go for a maintained dbg like x64dbg (it is very similar to olly in its GUI and basic functionalities).